# How can I load multiple scripts from org.webjars.bower

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am loading `angularjs + ui-router + ng-messages(using internet path)` using maven in my aplication this way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="/webjars/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.6.0/angular-messages.js">
 </script>
```

It's working fine but if I try to add ngStorage/ngMessages from org.webjars.bower this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/webjars/bower/ngstorage/0.3.11/ngstorage.js">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/webjars/bower/angular-messages/1.6.4/angular-messages.js">
```

I receive something like this:

> GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/bower/ngstorage/0.3.11/ngstorage.js
>   404 ()
>   or the same error for `ngmessages`

So I can't load them. Why?
What is the problem? The version of each script?

Comment: You are getting a 404, which means the resource wasn't found at that location. Check your file structure to see if the file is actually in that folder. If not, fix the path.

Comment: In maven repository org/webjars/bower/ngstorage and angular-messages exist...so..I don't understand what is wrong

Comment: While your browser is open, try navigating to `http://localhost:8080/webjars/bower/ngstorage/`. It may show you which folders are available at that directory. If not, try going a directive up. However, you permissions may forbid this. I'm guessing your build process is generating a target folder, so make sure the js file is in the correct place in the build target folder. If you could post a screenshot or give a tree describing your file structure that would help.

Comment: check this: https://postimg.org/image/n9l863zct/ https://postimg.org/image/fn3iyrevl/ and https://postimg.org/image/it8xonnt9/

Comment: Your m2 is where the files are stored for building later, not where they are served from in the live app. When you build, a folder called `target` or something similar should be generated. That is the folder that you need to check.

Comment: it s empty...link : https://postimg.org/image/quapnb8sz/

Comment: AngularJS is being served correctly right? Can you find the folder where `angular.js` is located in your filesystem?

Comment: I tried. I can't find it :(

Comment: but i don't understand why angularjs is working with the path src="/webjars/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js" and src="/webjars/bower/ngstorage/0.3.11/ngstorage.js" is not

Comment: Hei! Thanks Adrian for your help! I figured out how to solve my problem..Check out my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by my own.

I opened `Maven Dependencies` searched for ngstorage

[image: https://postimg.org/image/v1vsy4cel/]

and I saw what is path to the `ngstorage.js`...aparently the name of the script it's not `ngstorage.js` it's `ngStorage.js` and the path it's not `src="/webjars/bower/ngstorage/0.3.11/ngStorage.js"` is't `src="/webjars/ngstorage/0.3.11/ngStorage.js"`

I got confused because of the package of the artifact(`org.webjars.bower`)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Thanks again, Adrian! :)